# How can we determine the authenticity of an online psychologist's credentials?

Tags: criminology, validation, apa-style

I have come across an online psychologist who claims to be licensed and a member of the USA Psychology community. I would like to verify the authenticity of their credentials and ensure that they are a legitimate psychologist. Are there any specific online resources or databases that can assist with this verification process?

I used the ChatGPT to find some websites such as:

- The American Psychological Association (APA) or the Association of State and Provincial Psychology Boards (ASPPB) provides links to state boards' license lookup sites for psychologists. (URL: https://locator.apa.org/results/1/Usa/25/Farhang%20irani/?sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

Or

- The American Counseling Association (ACA), Association for Addiction Professionals (NAADAC), and Association of Marital & Family Therapy Regulatory Boards (AMFTRB) are other associations that provide license information for different specialties. (URL: https://www.betterhelp.com/advice/psychologists/are-online-psychologists-for-real/)

However, since I don't know which state the psychologist is licensed in, I am unsure if there is a website that allows for validation of psychology credentials across the entire USA. Should I ask this question here?

Additionally, I have seen some questions on Google like the following, but I have not been able to find a satisfactory answer:

How can we tell if a psychologist is real or fake if we find them online? (URL: https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-tell-if-a-psychologist-is-real-or-fake-if-we-find-them-online)

**Update 1:**

I have used the ChatGPT for emailing to apa.krg as you can see at below too ([ChatGPT link](https://www.phind.com/agent?cache=cllyus8gi000smn08nba7mp4a)):
[image]

And this the email sent photos and [link](https://www.apa.org/support/contact) :
[image]

Comment: Since you are asking a generic question, it is likely best to remove all references to a specific provider.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, every psychologist who sees online patients will either be working independently or working for a company that provides online therapy.

In either case, you can ask the psychologist, or the company for which they work, where they are licensed.

You can then look up their license to validate it on the official website for the licensing board for the correct jurisdiction.  To my limited knowledge, there is never a charge for this.  If someone tries to charge you, it is most likely a scam.

Make sure you verify they are *currently* licensed, and haven't had any disciplinary actions taken against them.

Note that many (most? all?) licensing boards may not tell you when a psychologist (or other professional) is currently under investigation, even for very serious matters.  For this, you will have to search court records, newspaper archives, disciplinary hearing records & notices, and law enforcement records.  These records may not be in the same jurisdiction(s) in which the psychologist is currently licensed to practice.

From horror stories I have repeatably heard from the USA, medical professionals, and the companies for which they work, rarely disclose their problematic histories to patients, even when it may impact the quality and safety of health care.

*(Please note that all the above is generic help to find relevant licensing information on any USA psychologist, and is not intended to be specific to any individual psychologist.)*